# Cast to custom class in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, class, casting

Once I've written my own custom class in PowerShell (let's say, `MyAwesomeClass`), how can I cast an object to it? I mean, given that I have a proper constructor, the following statement is ok

```
$var = [MyAwesomeClass]::new($anObject)
```

but the following one doesn't work

```
$var = [MyAwesomeClass]$anObject
```

How can I do this cast?

Comment: What happens when you check the type of: `[MyAwesomeClass]$var = $null`? Does it return a `$null` object of the type MyAwesomeClass?

Comment: No, when I do the cast I get this error message:
`InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "MyAwesomeClass"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class definition contains a constructor that takes exactly one of whatever type `$anObject` is as an argument, the cast to `[MyAwesomeClass]` will succeed:

```bsh
class MyAwesomeClass
{
  [object[]]$Array

  MyAwesomeClass([object[]]$array)
  {
    $this.Array = $array
  }

  # ...
}

# This will now work, assuming `$anObject` is an array
[MyAwesomeClass]$anObject
```

Alternatively, implement an implicit cast from the source type:

```bsh
class MyAwesomeClass
{
  [object[]]$Array

  hidden static
  [MyAwesomeClass] op_Implicit([object[]]$array){
    $newInstance = [MyAwesomeClass]::new()
    $newInstance.Array = $array

    return $newInstance
  }

  # ...
}
```

Comment: Are the casts ***case sensitive*** or not? E.g., would a cast to `[myawesomeclass]` be valid (not that it is a good idea)? What about "`[object]`" vs. "`[Object]`", "`[regex]`" vs. "`[Regex]`", or "`[psobject]`" vs. "`[PSObject]`" (the last two are not in this example)? Are there aliases in place that makes it *seem* to be case *insensitive*? Perhaps add a note about this to your answer?

Comment: OK, the last two are explained as "[type accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-7.1)" (aliases for .NET framework classes). `regex` (lower case) is an alias for .NET class `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` and `psobject` (lower case) is an alias for .NET class `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`. That doesn't explain `object[]`, though.